# Rows to Columns RDLC

Tags: sql-server, rdlc, dynamic-sql, qsqlquery

i have data in below format. this data is coming through SQL Query.[image]

i want to show it in below format either by query or by rdlc report. 
[image]

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried so far, maybe we can start from there

Comment: i tried to use pivot, but it comes with aggregate so it only show 1 row for each crew # when i use min or max ...

Comment: i am open to RDLC also. if someone can help to create a rdlc report with required format. i tried it also but same problem that when i put Crew # in column and empName in value then i have to select some aggregate function and then it will also show 1 row only.

Comment: If the maximum number of employees per group is fixed (and small), then there is no need for a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to make it.

From your expected result you can try to follow thoes step to make it.

1. use `row_number` function make row number by Name, because we need to `join` base on that row_number.
2. get the use `MAX` and `MIN` to make row number calendar table. from 1 to `max(rn)`. the table can let use `outer join`
3. declare a var `@tables` to make the `OUTER JOIN` execute SQL (each `LEFT JOIN` maen a group of `Crew#`).
4. declare a var `@col` to make column, which you want to select (Employee) from each table.
5. then use `execute` dynamic execute it.

look like this.

```
create table T
(
    Name varchar(50),
    Employee VARCHAR(50)
)

insert into T values ('Crew#1','TR123');
insert into T values ('Crew#1','311');
insert into T values ('Crew#2','DDD');
insert into T values ('Crew#2','12121');
insert into T values ('Crew#1','SDDAS');
insert into T values ('Crew#3','31114312');
insert into T values ('Crew#3','DD14124D');
insert into T values ('Crew#3','1214124121');
insert into T values ('Crew#3','SDD412AS');


DECLARE @tables AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @col AS NVARCHAR(MAX);



SET @tables = STUFF((SELECT distinct ' LEFT JOIN ' + ' (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Name = '''+Name+''') '+QUOTENAME(Name)+' on t1.smallRN = '+QUOTENAME(Name)+'.rn' 
            FROM T
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SET @col = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(Name)+'.Employee as '''+ QUOTENAME(Name) +''''
            FROM T
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @col = substring(@col,1, len(@col))

set @query = '
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) rn
    FROM T 
),CTE1 AS(
    SELECT MIN(rn) smallRN,MAX(rn) bigRN
    FROM CTE 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT smallRN+1,bigRN
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE smallRN < bigRN
)
SELECT '+@col+' 
FROM CTE1 t1 ' + @tables

execute(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=757a75aaf0f0e18c7633e27c21449e92)

Answer (score 1):

1. Creatin tbale

First we will create a temp table where we will stock the data that you have and your table

```
    create table #table1 
(
[Crew Name] varchar(500) , 
Employee varchar(500) 
)

INsert into #table1
values (....)
select * from #table1
```

[image]

2. Dynamic selection

then we will create a dynamic query to get the columns that we have, that way we can add as much crews as we want,

```
declare @DynamicPivotQuery as nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnName as nvarchar(max)

select @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName +',','') + QUOTENAME([Crew Name])
from (select distinct [Crew Name] from #table1) as Country

set @DynamicPivotQuery = N'select ' +@ColumnName + '
                            from #table1 
                              Pivot ( MAX(Employee)
                                FOR [Crew Name] in (' +@ColumnName+')) as Pivoted 

                            '
exec (@DynamicPivotQuery)
```

this way we will get only the first row for every column
so we have to find a way to aggregate and get the other columns as well just to demonstrate i will union the Mmin also this is where i stoped my testes but you can do more then this with some testes

[image]

now the union :

```
declare @DynamicPivotQuery as nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnName as nvarchar(max)

select @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName +',','') + QUOTENAME([Crew Name])
from (select distinct [Crew Name] from #table1) as Country

set @DynamicPivotQuery = N'select ' +@ColumnName + '
                            from #table1 
                              Pivot ( MAX(Employee)
                                FOR [Crew Name] in (' +@ColumnName+')) as Pivoted 
                                union 
                                select ' +@ColumnName + '
                                    from #table1 
                                     Pivot ( MIN(Employee)
                                     FOR [Crew Name] in (' +@ColumnName+')) as Pivoted
                            '

exec (@DynamicPivotQuery)
```

here is the result :

[image]

if you follow this way i'm sure that you will find a way to union all the result

Answer (score 0):

You can add this result into a temp table
then add a column which will be a reference into this temp table
then use pivot function

To know more about pivot Visit : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/pivot-and-unpivot-u-sql

you can use also SSIS to a very handy tool and easy to use

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about column reference to temp table

Comment: i will add an answer to explain more

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic PIVOT if you dont have a set Crew columns.

```
DECLARE @ColumnString VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @ColumnHeadrer VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)

CREATE TABLE #ColumnValue
(
    Value VARCHAR(500),
    ColumnHeader VARCHAR(256)
)

INSERT INTO #ColumnValue (Value, ColumnHeader)
SELECT DISTINCT '[' + CrewName + ']', 
  'ISNULL(' + CrewName + ','''') AS ' + CrewName 
FROM CrewTable

SELECT @ColumnString = COALESCE(@ColumnString + ',', '') + Value,
    @ColumnHeadrer = COALESCE(@ColumnHeadrer + ',', '') + ColumnHeader
FROM #ColumnValue

SET @sql =
'
SELECT ' + @ColumnHeadrer + '
FROM
(
    SELECT Employee,
        CrewName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CrewName ORDER BY CrewName) AS rnk
    FROM CrewTable
) AS P
    PIVOT
(
    MAX(Employee) FOR [CrewName] IN ('+@ColumnString+')
) AS pv
'


EXEC (@sql)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Crew #'s are dynamic. so i can't fix them

Comment: If you give me your table structure and data I will create you a dynamic pivot

Comment: the output i am showing here is coming from many tables. you can use this output as initial input. consider these are two columns in a table with data in provided.

Comment: Hi @Shahid I edited my script, so now it dynamical pickup the crew columns.